# Middleware Json web token auth type error in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, middleware

hi this is the token middleware function I have an issue in auth function when I use it I get an error about the argument of type '...' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandlerParams...' but I don't find anything about RequestHandlerParams

```
export interface IGetUserAuthInfoRequest extends Request {
  user: any;
}

const tokenDecode = (req: Request) => {
  try {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
    if (bearerHeader) {
      const token = bearerHeader.split(" ")[1];
      return jsonwebtoken.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET) as JwtPayload;
    }
    return false;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
};

const auth = async (
  req: IGetUserAuthInfoRequest,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): Promise<any> => {
  const tokenDecoded = tokenDecode(req);
  if (!tokenDecoded) return responseHandler.unauthorized(res);
  const user = await userModel.findById(tokenDecoded.data);
  if (!user) return responseHandler.unauthorized(res);

  req.user = user;
  next();
};
```

I get an error when I use this auth function
this is my router and error

```
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.get("/", tokenMiddleware.auth, reviewController.getReviewsOfUser);
```

Error

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: IGetUserAuthInfoRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: IGetUserAuthInfoRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
        Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
          Property 'user' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' but required in type 'IGetUserAuthInfoRequest'.
```

Answer (score 0):

your error message tells everything.

You've created an interface `IGetUserAuthInfoRequest` which is a contract that extends `Request`.

In your auth function, you require the request to satisfy the interface you just declared.

However, your error tells that the request you pass in to the auth function doesn't have the `user` property, as this is needed with your interface.

So you should remove the interface and replace it by the `Request`.

I assume you want to retrieve the user information by using its id, contained in the jwt. But you don't need to define an interface, because we cannot verify from the request that we have the user id in the jwt. We need to decode it, as you do it by calling tokenDecode().

Some tips on interfaces' names, you shouldn't name it with a 'I' prefix as it is not recommended by TypeScript anymore and pollute your code.

Some resources;

- https://jwt.io/introduction/
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html#interfaces
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/typescript-implement-interfaces/2-interfaces-typescript